# Polynomials and adjacency matrix of a graph

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, polynomials, spectral-graph-theory

If $p$ is some polynomial such that $[p(A)]_{ij} \neq 0$ and $A$ is the adjacency matrix of a graph. Does the existence of such a $p$ say anything about the graph?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus We can't construct the linear independence argument. Can you kindly flesh it out?

Comment: Suppose $\sum_{i=0}^D \alpha_i A^i = 0$. If $x,y$ are at distance $D$ then $(A^i)_{xy} \neq 0$ only for $i = D$, so $\alpha_D = 0$. Now if $x,y$ are at distance $D-1$ then for $i \leq D-1$, $(A^i)_{xy} \neq 0$ only for $i = D-1$, so $\alpha_{D-1} = 0$. And so on.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21843/discussion-on-question-by-user6818-polynomials-and-adjacency-matrix-of-a-graph).

Answer (score 2):

I think it's more interesting when you have a polynomial $p$ such that $p(A)=0$.  Such a polynomial tells us that if $p_{ij}(r)$ is the number of paths of length $r$ from $i$ to $j$, then $p_{ij}(r)$ satisfies a degree-$d$ recurrence (where $d=\mathrm{deg\,} p$) which is independent of $i$ and $j$.  (By the Cayley-Hamilton theorem, the characteristic polynomial of $A$ *is* such a polynomial, so such a recurrence exists.)